# Constructor Undefined for Java Generics Class

Tags: java, generics

I know there's a couple other threads on this but none of them have been able to fix my issue. I'm sure its a simple error however I'm new to java generics and pretty lost.

I have a node class with the following:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T label;

    public Node(T label) {
        if(label.equals(null)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The parameter is null!");
        }
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

And an Edge class made up of Two nodes and a label of type T

```
public class Edge<N, T> {

    private Node<T> startNode;
    private Node<T> endNode;
    private T nodeLabel;

    public Edge(Node<T> start, Node<T> end, T label) {
        if(start == null || end == null || label == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("One of the parameters was null!");
        }
        this.startNode = start;
        this.endNode = end;
        this.nodeLabel = label;
    }
}
```

I than try to create an edge with the following variables

```
Node<String> node1 = new Node<String>("A");
Node<String> node2 = new Node<String>("B");
Node<String> node3 = new Node<String>("C");
Node<String> node4 = new Node<String>("D");
String label1 = "1";
int label2 = 7;
Edge<Node<String>, String> edge1 = new Edge<Node<String>, String>(node1, node2, label1);
Edge<Node<String>, Integer> edge2 = new Edge<Node<String>, Integer>(node3, node4, label2);
```

When creating edge2 it gives me the error "The constructor Edge< Node< String>, Integer>(Node,Node, int) is undefined

Comment: Have you noticed that `Edge` isn't actually using the `N` parameter?

Comment: In the constructor for Edge, you've written `(..., T label)` There is no `int` value being accepted anywhere

Comment: `label.equals(null)` would throw a NPE if `label` is null. You probably mean `label == null`.

Comment: What is the point of the `N` type variable? It seems unused.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor callings, type of 'label' in Node class and type of 'label' in Edge class should have the same type of object.

So there is not a problem with the following line. Because you used the 'String' type for all of them.

```
Edge<Node<String>, String> edge1 = new Edge<Node<String>, String>(node1, node2, label1);
```

But there is a problem with the other line, because of you used 'String' type for Edge class, and you used 'int' type for Node class.

```
Edge<Node<String>, Integer> edge2 = new Edge<Node<String>, Integer>(node3, node4, label2);
```

For the solution you can define a constructor in Edge class like that:

```
public Edge(Node<String> start, Node<String> end, Integer label) { ... }
```

or

You can change the type of 'label2' as 'String' like that:

```
String label2 = "7";
```